# How to adjust the log output level of GTK4?

Tags: linux, gtk

When developing an application based on GTK4, a log will be printed every time it is started. How can I get rid of it?

```
(conquerdocker:17460): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:13:21.962: Unknown key gtk-button-images in /home/aszswaz/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini

(conquerdocker:17460): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:13:21.962: Unknown key gtk-menu-images in /home/aszswaz/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini

(conquerdocker:17460): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:13:21.963: Unknown key gtk-toolbar-style in /home/aszswaz/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
```

Comment: I would try to make a backup of this file, `/home/aszswaz/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
`, then remove the lines including the three unknown keys as you've shown above. See if the warnings disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about having any log output when you are executing your program, you could call your program and redirect the logging output to "/dev/null", such as:

```
./your_program_name > /dev/null
```

Alternatively, since your program is most likely a GUI program and doesn't require a terminal/console window, you could set up a desktop file similar to the following example.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=GtkProgramName
Icon=/home/username/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/GTK.png
Categories=Utilities;
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/to/your/Programs/your_program_name
```

The key attribute here is the "Terminal=false" attribute which will run your program without a terminal, and therefore a user would not see spurious messages.  Desktop files usually are placed in the "~/.local/share/applications folder" and have a permission mask of "rw-rw-r--".

You might give those options a try.

Regards.

Comment: This will make print() useless. What I want is to disable GTK4 from outputting this kind of log by configuring GTK4.